# Is it possible to have a custom category namespace in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, namespaces, mediawiki, categories

I'm currently setting up a Wiki for a friend of mine and me with the purpose of a centralized collaborative music system with tabs, lyrics, connections etc.

Categories for songs, albums, interprets etc. are very helpful here (and we don't want to miss them), but we are continually facing the problem of longer and longer internal links and a decreasing readability, because we have to suffix every song with "(Song)" and every album with "(Album)" etc. The reason for this is the existence of ambiguities between songs, albums and interprets, like when a song has the same name as the album it is in.

I also stumbled across [namespace aliases](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:$wgNamespaceAliases), but this doesn't solve the ambiguities. The same applies to all extensions available [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:All_extensions).

What I would like to do is creating a new namespace ("Album" for example), so I can get rid of the suffixes. I am aware of how to add namespaces etc. as described [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces), [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Namespace) and [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Namespaces), but I didn't find any information on having them behave as if they were categories, i. e. putting `[[Album:Whatever]]` at the end of a page `Song:Whatever` would have the song included in the category `Album:Whatever` and if I want to output the category Link without the prefix, I would type `[[:Album:Whatever|Whatever]]`.

Does anyone know a way of adding a custom namespace "derived" from the category namespace like above? Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not completely getting you, because this sounds to me like an overcomplicated way of doing things. Why not simply use a template?

You can have a template named "Album" (or "Albumcat", or something similar) that looks like this:

```
<includeonly>[[Category:Album:{{{1}}}]]</includeonly>
```

Then you can simply include it on the article page:

```
{{Album|Urban Hymns}}
```

...and the article will categorized as "Album:Urban Hymns".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm going to use templates anyway later. My problem still is having artists, albums and songs with the same name. Custom namespaces would do the trick without a need for a respective suffix like `... (Song)`, but then I lose the ability to categorize by them. Prefixing the category name as in your answer makes the link name even longer and it would mean some overhead in typing when you search for it (I know, MediaWiki search facilities are horrible out-of-the-box, but I cannot use the respective extensions). I'll add some ideas about sub pages to the original question.

Comment: As there are no other ideas around, I awarded your answer with the bounty before it expires. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks :-)
Just to see if there's anything to do - how do you visualize your final categories to look like? "Category:Album-Something", "Category:Something (Album)", or are you just hoping to have multiple category namespaces not just for categorizing to begin with, but for viewing as well - "Album:Something", which will be a category page?

Comment: At the moment I have normal pages like `Bla (Song)`, `Bla (Album)` and category pages like `Category:Bla (Artist)`, `Category:Jazz (Genre)` and so on. I think I'll try to rename the category namespace to something like `C:`, append `Genre:` etc. and finally the actual title like `C:Artist:Whoever`. Maybe I should even abbreviate like `C:A:Whoever`. I still have to move albums to the category namespace. We already use the wiki and I'll try this on a test system later.

Comment: Another thing is: 2 songs have identical titles, but different content, different artists and so on. As a disambiguation I thought of subpages like `Song:Whatever/Artist One`. Same would apply to albums.

Comment: Aliasing the category namespace is very easy - just add the following to LocalSettings.php:
```$wgNamespaceAliases['C'] = NS_CATEGORY;```
(see here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespaceAliases)